# Gains and performance degradation when caching MySQL results

Tags: php, mysql, performance, caching, load

I have seen that some frameworks cache results from the database using usual files in the filesystem (not considering memory cached data for this case) and invalidate those once a change is made to the database or a specific TTL is over. Since the database is a file as well it seems kind of redundant to me besides in a use-case with a LOT of concurrent SELECT queries to the database from different sources to distribute the load to different files.

Is there any reason to use this caching technique for small private projects with way less and almost negligible traffic and concurrency besides a decent design and abstraction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Rule of Thumb:  Don't put a cache in front of a cache.  MySQL already does a not of work to avoid doing I/O; the cache you described seems to add to the I/O load.

Furthermore, if the caching mechanism adds to the RAM consumption, then it takes away from RAM that could otherwise be used to speed up MySQL.  For example, don't put memcached on the same server with MySQL.  Memcached needs lots of RAM.

KISS -- You are don't a small project?  Why complicate it with something that is unlikely to buy much benefit.

If your application is slow, then it is probably because of

1. a missing 'composite' index;
2. a poorly formulated `SELECT`;
3. any of a dozen less common, but simple to fix, causes.

but rarely because of not using an extra cache.

Answer (score 0):

Caching helps with two things:

- Big data sets, complex queries (joins, unions, sub-queries, etc)
- Database server query parsing

The questions to ask yourself when dealing with caching:

- Does my data change often?
- Do I get speed increase if I use it?

If your data changes often or the performance gains are negligible, I would suggest against caching. It's another thing to maintain and make sure that it isn't corrupted, etc. If the performance is significantly better then go for it.

Also file-based caching is usually slow and used only for big datasets